# jQuery Ajax send parameters from one server to another

Tags: php, ajax, networking

I'm trying to send parameters from one server to another. It works fine in my localhost, but when I try in my real server it doesn't work. This is my code:

index.php (server 1):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {


    $(".sendbutton").click(function(){

    //Save the link in a variable called element
    var element = $(this);

    //Find the id of the link that was clicked
    var del_id = $("#id").val();

   //Built a url to send
  var info = 'id=' + del_id;

   $.ajax({
   type: "get",
   datatype: "application/json",
   contentType: "text/plain",
   url: "getdata.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
   },
  error: function(xhr,textStatus,err)
  {
     alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
     alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
     alert("status: " + xhr.status);
     alert("text status: " + textStatus);
    alert("error: " + err);
    alert("no good "+JSON.stringify(err));
   }
  });

  });

   });
   </script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

  <body>
   <input type="text" id="id" name="id"/>
   <input type="button" value="Send" class="sendbutton"/>
   <div id="result">...data...</div>
   <div id="log"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

getdata.php : (another server)

```
 <?php
//check errors
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
//error_reporting(-1);

//connections with database 
include('connect.php');

//take the value of the previous id
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("select * FROM generator_brand WHERE idGB='$id'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result['manufacturer'];
?>
```

The error I'm getting is: readystate=4, state=0, error=undefined. Please some help :) what could the error be???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax generally doesn't let you send a request to a different server from that which you loaded the HTML page.

You'll need to look at enabling cross-site scripting or JSONP on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I found the same answer before :). Just need to know how to use the JSONP properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that another server means that files are not stored in the same place, instead of relative path

`url: "getdata.php",`

you should try putting absolute path, e.g.

`url: "http://example.com/getdata.php"`

Comment: Yep I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to see if your browser is blocking the cors request ( from the console debugger). In that case, enable cors headers in the php. Just a speculation, i don't know anything in php.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone having the same problem, you must use JSONP  for cross-domain and add this in the header:

```
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I read that this is not safe, so if you want to let only specific domain enter to your server, you could use:

```
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.domain.com');
```

Thanks